# Looking for Master-Master Replication Postgresql Windows

Tags: postgresql, replication

Looking for master-master replication with PostgreSQL for Windows. I look in the wiki https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling but all master-master tools are for linux.

Comment: Bucardo should work as it is implemented in Perl.

Comment: Bucardo will not currently work on Windows

Comment: Then have a look at [HA-JDBC](http://ha-jdbc.github.io/doc.html) or [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SymmetricDS looking good 10x.